# MySQL uploading data where one column in specific date format

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Good day everyone,

I am trying to upload a csv file that has 4 columns into a MySQL database. Columns are:

```
user_id, user_name, user_screenname, user_created
```

The *user_created* column has date values in the following format:

```
Tue Nov 14 22:33:19 GMT 2017
Fri Mar 08 16:10:13 UTC 2013
```

I am trying to upload all the data into a table that has defined datatypes: *user_id* being a *BIGINT(20)* and all the other columns *VARCHAR(45)* including the *user_created* column as well.

I want to try and execute the following query to upload the data and format the values in the *user_created* column so that it's stored properly in the database, but my question is how do I emphasize the timezone  abbreviations in the *STR_TO_DATE()* statement as there is no specific specifier description as per the [documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/STRTODATEstrformat.htm) I found. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Data/users_data.csv' 
INTO TABLE new_schema.user 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(user_id, user_name, user_screenname, @user_created_at)
SET user_created_at = STR_TO_DATE(@user_created_at, '%W %b %e %H:%i:%s GMT/UTC?? %Y);
```

I tried uploading using all the time/date related datatypes in mysql but as you would imagine all give warnings that the format is incorrect to be stored as any of the given datatypes.

Comment: Can you please tell the format of date in csv. Just you need a `to_date(your_date,'your_format') ` meaning whichever format you may have you can write it in the to_date function (your_format) in this case. Just make sure the format is the exact copy of your csv date format.

Comment: The date format in the CSV is *Tue Nov 14 22:33:19 GMT 2017*. In my query I am specifying it as `STR_TO_DATE(@user_created_at, '%W %b %e %H:%i:%s ??GMT/UTC?? %Y')` but I don't know how to specify the GMT/UTC bit as the data in the csv has multiple timezone abbreviations such as BST etc..

Comment: use `to_date(trunc(your_date),'%W %b %e') ` check if this works I just tried to remove time and extra part in datetime n then converted but idk about nested functions work or not in this case. Can check it out

Comment: Working solution can be found in the below question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381798/formatting-specific-date-to-required-format-in-notepad