# formatting specific date to required format in notepad++

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, datetime, notepad++

Good day everyone,

I have a data set in a csv file that has the following date formatting:

```
Tue Jun 16 18:01:56 BST 2009
Thu Aug 20 09:40:51 BST 2015
```

I am working on a MySQL database where the data needs to be uploaded into a **DATETIME** column thus the required format is presented below. The timezone abbreviations need to be removed completely, I am able to do that with find/replace as well as day abbreviations. So only the month abbreviations need to be converted to numbers and the year placed in the beginning:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

I know I can use CTRL+F to find and replace specific values in NP++. But as you might've guessed the date combinations in the file can be different. I have researched that it can be accomplished with a regular expression but I am not familiar with that at all. Are there any expert users who can advise how I could write the necessary expression to format and replace my dates? Thank you in advance.

Comment: MySQL's  [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). has ways to parse out CVS files and data within them using MySQL user variables.. Something like this should work   `LOAD DATA INFILE .... (<columns> @datetime) SET <columns>, @datetime =   STR_TO_DATE(..., LEFT(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import the data in a temporary, varchar column as-is, then use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert it to date time:

```
UPDATE yourdata
SET actual_datetime = STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(temp_datetime, 5, 16), SUBSTRING(temp_datetime, 25, 4)),
    '%b %d %H:%i:%s %Y'
)
```

[Tests for `STR_TO_DATE` function](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=b626f66bc1a8206bd48228524b493025)